# expected [END_OBJECT] but got [FIELD_NAME], possibly too many query clauses error in kibana

Tags: json, elasticsearch, kibana

when I am trying to comprise a compound bool query that has a fuzzy must requirement and several should reqs with one being a wildcard, I run into this error message. So far, no alterations to the syntax have helped me to resolve this issue.

The query:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": {
                "fuzzy": {
                    "message": "<fuzzy string>",
                    "fuzziness": "auto"
                }
            },
          "should": [
            { "query": { "message": "<string>" } },
            { "query": { "message": "<string>" } },
            { "wildcard": 
                {
                    "query": { "message": "<partial string*>"}
                } 
            }
          ],
          "minimum_should_match": "50%"
        }
    } 
}
```

The text inside `<>` is replaced with my searched string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `query` with `match` in your `bool/should` clause:

```
> {   "query": {
>      "bool": {
>       "must": {
>         "fuzzy": {
>           "message": "<fuzzy string>",
>           "fuzziness": "auto"
>         }
>       },
>       "should": [
>         {"match": {"message": "<string>"}},                        <-- here
>         {"match": {"message": "<string>"}},                        <-- and here
>         {"wildcard": {"query": {"message": "<partial string*>"}}}
>       ],
>       "minimum_should_match": "50%"
>     }   } }
```

Comment: the exchange of "query" for "match" in the places you mentioned has  not changed the result at all :\ I have gotten the same error again

Comment: How long are those strings between `<...>`?

Comment: fuzzy is 5 characters, first should is 3, second one is 6 chars, and the wildcard is 4 chars and then a * wildcard